# Appcelerator Alloy - Require Android Menu

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, require, appcelerator-mobile, android-menu

I got a Problem with the Require src="menu" with Alloy. I get an compile error when I want to import my Menu via the Require XML-Tag.

my Menu.xml:

```
<Alloy>
<Menu id="menu">
    <MenuItem onClick="doSomething" title="Item 1">
    <MenuItem onClick="doSomething" title="Item 2">
    <MenuItem onClick="doSomething" title="Item 3">
    <MenuItem onClick="doSomething" title="Item 4">
</Menu>
</Alloy>
```

my index.xml:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="index">
        ....a tableview or something...
        <Require src="menu">
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Now when I compile I get:

```
[ERROR] Alloy compile failed
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

and a few lines above:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined
```

However,

if I put the Menu directly into index.xml, everything compiles fine...

Comment: Assuming `Menu.xml` is in the same directory change `<Require src="menu">` to `<Require src="Menu"/>`

Comment: Holy Hamster!
ehm. that didnt help :(
I actually changed everything to lowercase, since my menu.xml is also writtin in lowercase. only <Menu>-Tag is in uppercase.

Comment: Where in the source is `nodeName`?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your menu.js file? That is what the require command is looking for, not the XML file

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it with Window tags, as in:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window>
        <Menu id="menu">
            <MenuItem id="menu1" onClick="doSomething" />
            <MenuItem id="menu2" onClick="doSomethingElse" />
        </Menu>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Hope it helps.